# Trouble installing prezto

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh, prezto

I was a oh-my-zsh user but decided to switch to prezto. I followed the steps on their github page: https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto

Uninstalled oh-my-zsh, git cloned prezto. Not sure whether I understand step 3 clearly but now I do have .zshrc, .zprofile, .zpreztorc under my home dir. However, when I open a new tab with zsh, I still see the most basic zsh setting. (for example, I didn't see the sorin theme). Any idea on how to debug my installation?

I am running this on latest OS X with iTerm2.

Comment: THANKS YOU SO MUCH. Here's a BATCH of cookies – no seriously, I would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. I didn't have .zshrc linked correctly. Some discussion can be found at https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/231

After deleting .zshrc and re-run step 3. Prezto works fine for me now.